# Redondear 2 decimales en Java

Tags: java, float

Buenas, tengo este método realizado en Java y el resultado que me devuelve es un numero con muchos decimales, quisiera alguna forma para que me devolviese dos decimales únicamente.

Código:

```
public static float calcularMedia(int[] notas)
    {
        float resultado = 0;

        for(int nota: notas)
        {
            resultado+=nota;
        }
        return resultado/notas.length;      
    }
```

Comment: Si devuelves un `float`,eso es lo normal. De todas maneras, cual es es problema con que tenga varios decimales? Otra cosa es si quieres mostrar lo devuelto por pantalla como un `String`,en ese caso si puedes formatear la salida

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar esta función que te devuelve siempre todos los numeros que tienen decimales con el formato que le pasas, pero omite decimales para los numeros que no tienen:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
for (int nota : notas) {
    Double d = nota.doubleValue();
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
}
```

Comment: Perfecto este método, gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Si se trata de imprimir en consola, puedes usar `System.out.printf` o `String.format`. Ejemplo

Usando `System.out.printf`:

```
float f = 12.34567f;
System.out.printf("El número redondeado: %.2f\n", f);
```

Usando `String.format`:

```
float f = 12.34567f;
System.out.println(
    String.format("El número redondeado: %.2f", f)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto redondeará a dos decimales:

```
nota = Math.round(nota * 100d) / 100d;
```

A tres decimales:

```
nota = Math.round(nota * 1000d) / 1000d;
```