# Error en redondeo de decimales en Java

Tags: java, android

Estoy probando una función de redondeo en java con Android Studio, y observo que no siempre me devuelve el resultado correcto, con dos números de tipo double con 15 decimales el primero no me hace el redondeo correcto y el segundo lo redondea correctamente, aparentemente los dos números son similares pero el resultado es distinto.

A ver si alguien puede explicar por que me sucede esto, le estoy dando vueltas y no le encuentro lógica.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

double numDoble1 = 0.00, numDoble2 = 0.00, numDoble3 = 0.00;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
    numDoble1 = 7.555068493150685;
    numDoble1 = redondearDecimales ( numDoble1, 2 );
    numDoble2 = 7.614246575342465;
    numDoble2 = redondearDecimales ( numDoble2, 2 );
    numDoble3 = 0.00;
}


public static double redondearDecimales(double valorInicial, int numeroDecimales) {
    double parteEntera, resultado;
    resultado = valorInicial;
    parteEntera = Math.floor(resultado);
    resultado=(resultado-parteEntera)*Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales);
    resultado=Math.round(resultado);
    resultado=(resultado/Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales))+parteEntera;
    return resultado;
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes tú por *redondeo correcto*? ¿Qué arroja y qué debería arrojar? Por otra parte, tus valores no son de tipo decimal, son de tipo doble que no es lo mismo ([ver aquí por ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3413448/5587982)), existe un tipo específico para decimal en Java.

Comment: Aquí hay una pregunta que puede servirte. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/97868/169744

Comment: El redondeo que pretendo es que si el tercer decimal es 5 o mayor redondear hacia arriba el segundo y si es 4 o menor hacia abajo.

Comment: Gracias Mateo, tu método si que me da todos los resultados correctos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te limitas a hacer solo lo necesario no obtienes ningún error.

Con esto quiero decir que no le encuentro utilidad a sumar y restar `parteEntera`.

Así funciona bien:

```
public static double redondearDecimales(double numero, int decimales) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimales);
    var desplazado = numero * factor;
    var redondeado = Math.round(dezplazado)
    return redondeado / factor;
}
```

---

Si te interesa saber por qué los resultados no son exactos, ya hay una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/169744) al respecto.